# redis-py AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, redis

I installed redis-py on CentOS and Ubuntu. On both I get the same error when trying to access it.

```
redis-py AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
```

If I use the python prompt in the same directory as the source this will work:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

but if I change directories it will give the error.

```
>>> import redis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "redis.py", line 4, in <module>
    print redis.__version__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Trying with a `.py` script always gives the error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it. Probably a newbie Python thing...

Comment: Could you give us more information on how you installed redis-py

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're naming a module you're working on `redis.py` and Python is importing that instead of the real `redis` module. Don't do that, or change `sys.path` to make sure the current working directory is *last* rather than first in the lists of directories to search.

Answer (score 0):

i have this error in tornado and it was because i install redis on python 2.7 and install in python3 too , i uninstall redis from python2.7 and re_install in python3 and solve the Problem!